# Already installed Pygame module, but when try to run pygame code it shows error

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 6, in 
    import random, pygame, sys
ImportError: No module named pygame

Comment: We need more information. The operating system, how you installed pygame, if you can import pygame in the Python shell (opened in the command-line/terminal) and if you have multiple Python versions installed.

Answer (score 0):

im no expert but from my experience but make sure you downloaded the right pygame for 1. your version of python and 2. your system+(32/64 bit).
also make sure in your `path` you have c:\python27 , c:\python27\scripts.